# How to cast a pointer in the free() function?

Tags: c, pointers, free

"warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]      "

the problem is here free((void*)c_array[i]); if you can explain me how to solve the problem, thank you!

```
static char* create_char_array() {
char* array = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*4);

array[0] = 'd';
array[1] = 'a';
array[2] = 'f';
array[3] = 'b';

return array;
}


static void delete_test_char_array(char* c_array, int len) {
  for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    free((char*)c_array[i]);
   }
free(c_array);
}

static void test_char_increasing_insertion_sort() {
char* array = create_char_array();
generic_increasing_insertion_sort((void**)array, 4, (ElementsCmp) compare_chars);

TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL('a', array[0]);
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL('b', array[1]);
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL('d', array[2]);
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL('f', array[3]);

delete_test_char_array(array, 4);
 }
```

Comment: How many times did you call `malloc`?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code as shown does not seem to make any sense. `c_array[i]` is a `char` and not a pointer and would not normally be freed. Unless there is some other non-conventional code when constructing `c_array`. So we need to see at least how `c_array` was allocated/defined.

Comment: You called `malloc` only once. So **you must call free() only once**, passing to it the same value that was returned by malloc.

Comment: I added that piece of code, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to free individual characters.  The `free` function only accepts pointers that were returned from `malloc`.

You only call `malloc` once, so only call `free` once.

```
static void delete_test_char_array(char* c_array) {
    free(c_array);
}
```